# Zero Padding in a variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

Below is my scenario :
Input value=1234
Input Range= 2

Expected output =1200

Input value=12345
Input Range= 3

Expected output =12000

The ask is replace the number of characters/digits from right with zero equivalent to the Input range

I have followed the below logic:

```
{
    "name": "RoundPad",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(1,pipeline().parameters.Range)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "TempPower",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(mul(int(variables('Power')),10))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable2",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "Power",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('TempPower')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable3",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "Output",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(mul(div(int(pipeline().parameters.Input),int(variables('Power') )),int(variables('Power'))))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "Input": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "1234"
            },
            "Range": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 2
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "TempPower": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "1"
            },
            "Output": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "Power": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "1"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any better way to do this rather than leveraging For each iteration and multiple variables?
I might be missing something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can take the substring from input value i.e., last n number of characters/digits, where n is the Range.
- Then subtract that number from the input value to get the desired result. The following is the complete pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "replace_range",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "sample1",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@substring(pipeline().parameters.input,sub(length(pipeline().parameters.input),pipeline().parameters.Range),pipeline().parameters.Range)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable2",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "res",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(sub(int(pipeline().parameters.input),int(variables('sample1'))))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "input": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "12345"
            },
            "Range": {
                "type": "int",
                "defaultValue": 3
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "sample1": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "res": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "prac": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-03-11T17:42:32Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Result when input value is 12345 and range is 3:

[image]